# path traversal vulnerabilities detected in code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code:

```
    def download_package(self, dist_dir):
        safe_list = ["prod","staging"]
        prod_dir = 'prod'
        staging_dir = 'staging'
        kp_dir = os.path.join(dist_dir, 'key_protect')
        for dir_name in [prod_dir, staging_dir]:
            try:
                if dir_name in safe_list:
                    my_dir = os.path.join(kp_dir, dir_name)
                os.makedirs(my_dir)
            except OSError, e:
                if e.errno == os.errno.EEXIST:
                    print("Target directories exist %s" % my_dir)
```

When I scan this code using HCL appscan it points me to issue at line `my_dir = os.path.join(kp_dir, dir_name)` and no issue is detected at `kp_dir = os.path.join(dist_dir, 'key_protect')` I am not sure what issue is there in this code as far as security goes. The scan indicates this code as subject to Path traversal attacks. Can someone help on this please?

Comment: What is the value of `my_dir` if `dir_name` is *not* in `safe_list`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how HCL appscan works, but the issue is due to the fact that the function accept a `dist_dir` parameter that is then used to issue side-effect producing command (i.e. `os.makedirs()`).
See the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) for more info on this kind of attack.

Quite possibly, the issue is triggered only by the second `os.path.join()` because `os.makedirs()` is called on the result from the second `os.path.join()` call (and not the first).

To prevent the vulnerability you should sanitize the content of `dist_dir`.

---

For example, you could be doing something like:

```
def download_package(self, dist_dir):
    if '../' not in dist_dir and '/..' not in dist_dir and '..' != dist_dir:
        prod_dir = 'prod'
        staging_dir = 'staging'
        kp_dir = os.path.join(dist_dir, 'key_protect')
        for dir_name in [prod_dir, staging_dir]:
            try:
                my_dir = os.path.join(kp_dir, dir_name)
                os.makedirs(my_dir)
            except OSError, e:
                if e.errno == os.errno.EEXIST:
                    print("Target directories exist %s" % my_dir)
```

Comment: I updated the question with how I tried to sanitize the path. It did not seem to help though..

Comment: I have edited my answer with a possible, but perhaps not very useful, approach.

Comment: I tried sanitizing with safe_list as well. It still detects error..

Comment: @coded in your code `dist_dir` still goes unchecked into `os.makedirs()`...

Comment: May complain but the above code is not vulnerable to path traversal.

Comment: I think its something to do with the for loop iteration. The item in the list gives error. In this case `dir_name`. There are multiple places in my code where I have a for loop and it errors out on all of them..

Comment: What about checking for absence of `..` like in the above (edited)?